# Почему это множественное наследование вызывает UB?

Tags: c++, наследование, gcc, множественное-наследование, неопределённое-поведение

Почему эта программа [вызывает срабатывание UBSan](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:28,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:28,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:28,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:28,startLineNumber:6),source:%27struct+B+%7B%0A++++char+space%5B1!%27100!%27000%5D%3B%0A++++virtual+%7EB()+%3D+default%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Astruct+C+%7B%0A++++virtual+%7EC()+%3D+default%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Astruct+D+:+B,+C+%7B%7D+d%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.568689256632524,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:etl,ver:trunk),(name:googletest,ver:trunk)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-fsanitize%3Dundefined%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.43131074336749,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.4%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.43131074336749,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)?

```cpp
struct B {
    char space[1'100'000];
    virtual ~B() = default;
};
struct C {
    virtual ~C() = default;
};
struct D : B, C {} d;

int main() {}
```

```
/app/example.cpp:8:8: runtime error: member call on address 0x0000005111e8 which does not point to an object of type 'C'
0x0000005111e8: note: object has a possibly invalid vptr: abs(offset to top) too big
 00 00 00 00  48 20 40 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              possibly invalid vptr
```

Если же переставить базовые классы `D : C, B`, то всё ок.

Comment: Со статическим `d` другая история. Тут санитайзер просто ругается на то, что размер объекта получается слишком большим.

Comment: Если `С` будет первым, то vptr будут идти друг за другом иначе между ними будет массив.

Comment: Выглядит как баг в санитайзере. Я бы зарепортил.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если зарепортишь, скинь ссылку сюда пж)

Comment: Нет уж, кто нашел, тот и репортит. :) Полезный навык.